# ggplot title and lists

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm having trouble with an apparently simple task. I'm running an dlply function for plot creation, and I want the title to call items from two variables "SITE" and "SP".

SITE and SP are both factors, both characters strings.

Here is my code:

```
plot.title<-"Index"
plot.subtitle<-SUBTOT_DATE$SP

p <- dlply(SUBTOT_DATE, .(SITE, SP),function(x){
ggplot(x, aes(YEAR, SUMIA, group=SITE))+
geom_point(size=3, color="red2") +
geom_line(size=1, color="red2") +

ggtitle(ggtitle(bquote(atop(.(plot.title), atop(italic(.(plot.subtitle)), "")))) )+

theme_bw()+
xlab("Year") +
ylab("Sum IA")+
theme(legend.direction ="vertical",legend.position = "bottom")+
guides(color=guide_legend(ncol=2))
})
```

My problem comes from this code:

```
plot.subtitle<-SUBTOT_DATE$SP
```

When i call SUBTOT_DATE$SP it returns a number instead of a character string.

When i call paste(SUBTOT_DATE$SITE,SUBTOT_DATE$SP) it only returns the first two items of both variables as title in the way i want to, but it remains the same for all plots.

When i call paste(SUBTOT_DATE$SITE[x],SUBTOT_DATE$SP[x]) i have this error:

```
Error in `[.default`(SUBTOT_DATE$SITE, x) : invalid subscript type 'list'
```

When i call paste(SUBTOT_DATE$SITE[[x]],SUBTOT_DATE$SP[[x]]) I have this error:

```
Error in `[[.default`(SUBTOT_DATE$SITE, x) : attempt to select more than one element
```

What am I doing wrong ? When i put my paste() function into the function(x) it doesnt work anymore.

Here is what i would, like to obtain as title in my plots:

```
> paste(SUBTOT_DATE$SITE," - ",SUBTOT_DATE$SP)[1:5]
[1] "RNN066-Valbois Vignes parc2bas  -  Aglais io (Linnaeus, 1758)" 
[2] "RNN066-Valbois Vignes parc3haut  -  Aglais io (Linnaeus, 1758)"
[3] "RNN066-Valbois Pel temoin  -  Aglais io (Linnaeus, 1758)"      
[4] "RNN066-Valbois Vignes parc3bas  -  Aglais io (Linnaeus, 1758)" 
[5] "RNN066-Valbois Vignes parc3bas  -  Aglais io (Linnaeus, 1758)"
```

For obscure reasons it renames all the plots with only the number 1.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: wouldn't `unique(SUBTOT_DATE$SP)` make more sense?

Comment: Still getting a number instead of a character string in first case, no changes in other cases.

Comment: I would love to help, but you've provided no reproducible example to work with, and so it is very unclear what your actual data structures are.

Comment: `plot.subtitle = factor("aa"); plot(1,1, main=bquote(italic(.(plot.subtitle))))` illustrates a problem with factors and `italic()`. You might want to try `plot.subtitle = unique(as.character(x$SP))` (inside the loop), maybe.

Answer (score 0):

Answered by baptiste:

The right syntax was:

```
paste(x$SITE,x$SP)
```